# Why is the alert triggered only on the 1st row of the table?

Tags: pine-script

I have a table that displays the 20 and 50 SMA crossovers of several tickers.
I put an alert to indicate me the tickers which undergo a bullish or bearish crossing but the alert only works for the 1st row of the table.

Example if the table displays:

```
Row 1: ETH
Row 2: BNB
Row 3: BTC
Row 4: SOL
```

So the alert fires only for ETH
Do you know where the problem can come from ? Thanks in advance

```
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id=stats, column=0, row=0, text= "Sma" , text_size=size.large, bgcolor=color.new(color.gray, 80), text_color=color.gray)
    
if barstate.isrealtime
    for i = 1 to 40 by 1
        table.cell(table_id=stats, column=0, row=i, text='', text_size=size.large, bgcolor=na, text_color=na)
    if array.size(Sma) > 0
        for i = 0 to array.size(Sma) - 1 by 1      
            table.cell(table_id=stats, column=0, row=i + 2, text=str.tostring(array.get(Sma, i)), text_size=size.large, text_color=array.get(a_01, i) ? color.green : color.red)
            // Alert
            alert(str.tostring(array.get(Sma, i)), freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert.freq_once_per_bar` will only trigger once per bar. If you need multiple alerts for multiple conditions, you need multiple `alert()` function calls.

Comment: Thanks, Yes (alert.freq_once_per_bar) only fires once per bar but for each tickers. In the case of the example, only ETH triggers the alert while the rest does not.